# Magento 2 How to prevent product save with custom condition using plugin 'aroundSave'?

Tags: magento2, product, plugin

I want to prevent to save the product with **my custom condition**, for that, I **want to use the plugin with method 'aroundSave'**,

- When the user clicks on 'Save & Duplicate' button I do not want to save the original product simply duplicate the product.
  Is the **plugin method is correct** or I **need to override the controller** or use **catalog_product_save_befor event**?

Anyone have any example please share.

for example,

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Save
{    
   public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save $subject, $result)
    {
      if (some condition == true)
          then save product
      else
            not save the product
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

That would be because the admin product form doesn't actually use `ProductRepository`, at least as of 2.2.2.

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php:

```
$product->save();
```

You haven't explained what you're actually trying to accomplish, but you would probably be better served by an observer on event `catalog_product_save_before` or `catalog_product_save_after`. Those are kicked off by the product resource model, so they should fire regardless of whether the product is saved via `ProductRepository` or directly.

Comment: please check updated question. thanks for your help.